# Upload Android APK on play store

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

Actually I already uploaded the APK file on the google play store.
But after first APK I changed the package name, and try to upload the new APK with new package name. But it is not allowed me to upload. I am getting the Your APK needs to have the package name "com.mobilet.mobile"

Please help.

Comment: You just can't upload the apk with a different package name.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the asker simply doesn't understand the basic requirements for publishing an app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make it short: You can't.

You will have to upload your app as a new application or reuse your old package name.